# How can I redirect to my particular Live Wallpaper preview from app instead of listview of wallpaper to select?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, live-wallpaper

Hi I'm working on android app where I need to redirect to my particular live wallpaper preview screen. Currently it open the list where it's lists all the wallpaper which available.

To select my wallpaper I have to pick anyone from that list then it send me on preview of my wallpaper. I want to skip list of the select live wallpaper screen and automatic redirect to set live wallpaper screen of particular wallpaper.

Below code simply open the listview which lists all the wallpaper

Thanks in advance.

```
private int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for API 15 and greater. :)

```
Intent i = new Intent();

                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15){
                    i.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);

                    String p = MyServiceClass.class.getPackage().getName();
                    String c = MyServiceClass.class.getCanonicalName();
                    i.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT, new ComponentName(p, c));
                }
                else{
                    i.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER);
                }
                startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```